# Eclipse 20.6: The WebSphere software catalog server is not available

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

We are trying to get started with IBM Liberty server for some batch processing. I installed Eclipse 20.6 build and then from market place installed IBM Websphere Liberty Profile, Developer tools.

Now, when i try to go to  Help --> Install Websphere Software..

[image]

i get this error:
"The WebSphere software catalog server is not available"

[image]

My proxy are set properly in eclipse. I am not sure what to do and been googling for hours now, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I dont have 20.x at hand, but you could try to download Liberty directly from https://wasdev.net and then add the server via `Servers` view in Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, i tried Eclipse Oxygen but same results. Yes i am able to install liberty server outside eclipse and add to Servers view in Eclipse.  I am behind corporate proxy and i think that is causing it. I have tried adding proxy in eclipse.ini,  preferences --> network connections but still not working.

Comment: I have a similar problem, with Eclipse 2020-09. I'm not behind a proxy, the first time I try to add a liberty server, it installs something. Restarted eclipse, after this installation, the IBM folder in the server definition is not even shown anymore! On the other hand it seems I can manage to add a liberty server on oxygen even behind a proxy https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_config_installutility.html can be helpful